# control plot width in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

plot1 and plot2's plot width differ. Because, plot2's plot width shrinks automatically due to long lable number. Is there a way to force the width length to certain number(so that multiple graphs have same plot width)?

```
ll <- data.frame(x=c(1,10),y=c(1,10))
plot1 <- ggplot(data=ll,aes(x,y))+geom_point()
ll2 <- data.frame(x=c(1,10),y=c(100000,100000000))
plot2 <- ggplot(data=ll2,aes(x,y))+geom_point()
print(plot1)
print(plot2)
```

Comment: Use `plot_grid` from the `cowplot` package to lay out the plots. Use the `align` argument to get the same panel widths/heights in each plot. See the help (`?plot_grid`) for details.

Comment: you could try `egg::set_panel_size()`

Comment: Thank you letting me know the plot_grid. The "align" worked. However I can't still adjust plot width to certain value in with the plot_grid. It's really strange that ggplot doesn't have like plot.width in theme().

Comment: You can fix the aspect ratio of the plot using `coord_fixed()` when you create the plot object. However, the physical size of the plot is something you determine when you render/save it in a file (as a PDF or PNG, for example) or as part of a document or web page. See [**here**](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/graphics-for-communication.html#saving-your-plots) for how to get the desired size and shape for your figures.